# I am getting a Bus Error 10 while implementing a Queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, circular-list

Can Someone tell me why am I facing a Bus Error 10 in the following code.

The code below implements a Queue using circular linked list.

I am inserting 3 and 5 into the list and later remove thrice from front. I have handled corner cases too.

Thanks,
Priyam Dhanuka

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        int val;
        Node *next;
        Node(int val)
        {
            this->val = val;
            this->next = this;
        }
};

void Enqueue(Node **rear, int val)
{
    Node * newNode = new Node(val);
    if((*rear) == NULL)
    {
        *rear = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node *front = (*rear)->next;
    (*rear)->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = front;
    *rear = newNode;

}
int Dequeue(Node **rear)
{

    if((*rear) == NULL)
        return -1;
    if((*rear)->next == (*rear))
    {

        int val = (*rear)->val;
        delete(*rear);
        *rear = NULL;

        return val;
    }

    Node *temp = (*rear)->next;
    Node *front = temp->next;
    int val = temp->val;
    (*rear)->next = front;
    delete(temp);
    return val; 
}
int main()
{
    Node *head;
    Enqueue(&head, 3);
    Enqueue(&head, 5);
    cout<<Dequeue(&head)<<endl;
    cout<<Dequeue(&head)<<endl;
    cout<<Dequeue(&head)<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: *Can Someone tell me why am I facing a Bus Error 10 in the following code.* -- Have you used a debugger to debug your code?  Your first call to `Enqueue` is faulty.

Comment: `if((*rear) == NULL)` -- This goes wrong from the start.  You called this with an uninitialized `head` pointer and you're trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer.  Result for you -- bus error.